# How to use `expr` when there's an optional substring in the regex?

Tags: regex, expr

I want to find the `go[^ ]+` inside these two strings using `expr`. The output should be `1.17.6` and `1.18-becaeea119`.

```sh
go version go1.17.6 linux/amd64
go version devel go1.18-becaeea119 Tue Dec 14 17:43:51 2021 +0000 linux/amd64
```

However, the `devel` part is optional and I can't figure out a way to properly ignore it with `expr`.

```sh
expr "$(go version)" : ".*go version go\([^ ]*\) .*"
expr "$(go version)" : ".*go version devel go\([^ ]*\) .*"
```

Using normal regexes, I would just `(?: devel)?` it, but `expr` doesn't support `?` for some reason.

Is there any way to achieve this using `expr` in one command?

Comment: Did you try `.*go version\( devel\)\? go\([^ ]*\) .*` and take the match from group 2?

Comment: Looking at some third-party docs online, it seems like it's not possible to obtain `\2`. *If the pattern contains at least one regular expression subexpression, the string corresponding to `\1` shall be returned*. https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/expr.html#tag_04_50_13_01

Comment: It looks impossible then

Comment: Since you want to return the go.. part and the only way is that it returns the first group, you'll have to loosen it up after _version_. Could be its the only way. `.*go version.* go\([^ ]*\) .*`

Comment: See https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/String-expressions.html

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use

```js
.*go version.* go\([^[:space:]]*\) .*
```

**EXPLANATION**

```js
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  .*                       any character (0 or more times)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  go version               'go version'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  .*                       any character (0 or more times)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   go                      ' go'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \(                       group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^[:space:]]*            any character except: whitespace
                             characters (0 or more times)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \)                       end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                           ' '
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  .*                       any character (0 or more times)
```

Answer (score 0):

is that what you wanted?

```
.*go version [a-w ]*go\([^ ]*\) .*
```